MSW to mock a streaming API results in TypeError: Invalid state: The ReadableStream is locked
I'm trying to intercept and mock an API which returns a stream.
The test setup -
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";

const restHandlers = [
  http.post(`/path/to/my/api?jwt=jwt`, async () => {
    return makeResponse([JSON.stringify({ type: "text", payload: "text" })]);
  }),
];

const server = setupServer(...restHandlers);

beforeAll(() => {
   server.listen({ });
});


The makeResponse function -
function makeStream(data: string[], delay: number) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const arr = data.map((chunk: string) => encoder.encode(chunk));
  const underlyingSource = {
    start: (controller: ReadableStreamDefaultController) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        arr.forEach((chunk: Uint8Array) => controller.enqueue(chunk));
        controller.close();
      }, delay);
    },
  };
  return new ReadableStream<Uint8Array>(underlyingSource);
}

export function makeResponse(data: string[], delay = 0): Response {
  return new HttpResponse(makeStream(data, delay), { status: 200 });
}


How the API gets invoked -
export default async function fetchStream(
  jwt: string,
  controller: AbortController,
): Promise<ReadableStream<Uint8Array>> {
  const url = `/path/to/my/api?jwt=${jwt}`;
  const body = { body };
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    signal: controller.signal,
  });

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error("HTTP Error");
  }
  return response.body!;
}

My Test -
it("Submits input from side panel on click", async ()  => {
   render(<TestApp {...props} />);
   ...
   await user.click(submitButton);

});


I see an error at the following code -
const stream = await fetchStream(
    jwt,
    controller.current,
);
const reader = stream.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).getReader();


The Error -
TypeError: Invalid state: The ReadableStream is locked

I can confirm that the locked property is seen to be true as soon as it is received inside the fetchStream function.
Streaming works just fine when the application is running and connecting to real APIs.
